# Is there a Faster way for Large DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, loops

I am importing a dataset from Teradata into Python = approx. 54M records.  I am trying to create a  DataFrame with this data.

Here is my code:

```
import os
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_sql(cac, db, chunksize = 100000)

rows = []
for i in df:
    rows.append(i)

b = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

This process works - but takes a long time (more than 10 minutes...).  Is there a faster way to get this data into a DataFrame?

Comment: is it not possible to call pd.DataFrame(df) directly?

Comment: Why do you need the loop when pd.read_sql() returns a df?

Comment: @MatthewBorish When `chunksize` is specified, `read_sql` returns an iterator.

Comment: Why use `chunksize` if you want to create a single df with everything?

Comment: Perhaps `pd.concat(df)`?  Or just don't use `chunksize`?

Comment: Otherwise, have a look at this: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/faster-pandas-dask/

Comment: @barmar if I don't use chunksize, it takes a long time to import 54M records.  Python would read the entire 54M records into memory.  I figured that chunksize would prevent reading all of the records into memory, and save time.

Comment: @0x5453 pd.concat(df) seemed to take forever...after 10minutes, I stopped Python from processing.

Comment: @Laurent thanks I will read the documentation and try this dask module now...hopefully with success

Comment: But you're reading all 54M records into memory when you add them to the list in the chunked loop. Using `chunksize` is only helpful if you can discard a chunk after processing it.

Comment: @Barmar yes you're right... I haven't been able to get around this issue.  Seems like I'll just be stuck with the slow processing of 54M records into memory either way.

Comment: Doing anything with 54M records is going to be slow -- computers are fast, but they're finite.